# Typoscript If/Else?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have two forms in powermail 1.6 and want to change the **form action** according to the form uid.

I have the following code:

```
plugin.tx_powermail_pi1 {
    formaction >
    formaction = TEXT
    formaction {
        typolink {
             parameter = 280
             parameter.if {
                  equals.field = uid
                  value = 1618
             }
          ...
        }
    } 
}
```

The code is working - if the id of the form is 1618, then the form action leads to the page with the id 280.

But how can I make an `Else` statement to change the form action for another form id e.g. 1612 to page id 290?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it in a COA

```
formaction = COA
formaction.10 = TEXT
formaction.20 = TEXT
```

The .10 will handle the true condition.
The .20 will handle the else condition